# Jest mock variables of imported component

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking, babel-jest

I am trying to mock a variable (*auth*) inside my App component as it is doing conditional rendering. How should I do it without trying to export the variable itself? Been trying for a few days with various solutions but I can't seem to cover it, and now I am stuck.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import Routing from "./routes";
import useAuth from "./hooks/useAuth";
import SplashScreen from "./components/splashScreen/SplashScreen";

const App = () => {
  const content = useRoutes(Routing());
  const auth = useAuth();

  return (
    <>
      {auth.isInitialized ? content : <SplashScreen />}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

describe("App Unit Tests", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  });

  it("App should render", () => {
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });

 //Below fails 
 it("should render splashscreen", () => {
    jest.mock("./hooks/useAuth", () => ({
      isInitialized: false,
    }));
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("should render content", () => {
    jest.mock("./hooks/useAuth", () => ({
      isInitialized: true,
    }));
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(auth.isInitialized)` in `App.js` to check whether the value of `isInitialized` passed in the UT is actually taking effect.

Comment: It appears that it is always only returning false.

Comment: Tried even your long version answer, still the same issue, always false.

Comment: Updated the answer, the thing is that mocks should be created at suite level and if there are any changes required in the mock, they should be handled dynamically. This is what the update does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `auth`, the `useAuth` hook should be mocked into an object (say `mockUseAuth`) that has the `isInitialized` getter. The getter should return a `mockIsInitialized` value, that can be changed on per test case basis. Something like this :

```
let mockIsInitialized = true;

let mockUseAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: true
};

Object.defineProperty(mockUseAuth, 'isInitialized', {
  get: jest.fn(() => mockIsInitialized)
});

jest.mock('./hooks/use-auth', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => (mockUseAuth))
})

describe("App Unit Tests", () => {
 let wrapper;
 beforeEach(() => {
   wrapper = mount(
     <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
   );
 });

 it("App should render", () => {
   expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
 });

 it("should render splashscreen", () => {
   mockIsInitialized = false;
   expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
 });

 it("should render content", () => {
   mockIsInitialized = true;
   expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
 });
});
```

Comment: Although it pass the test, it doesn't cover that uncovered line. I even created 2 test for when it is true and false

Comment: Didn't cover the conditional rendering or the `const auth = useAuth();` assignment ?

Comment: Still says that this line is still uncovered: `auth.isInitialized ? content : <SplashScreen />`  Perhaps it has something to do with what to expect?

Comment: Can you add an update to the question (with the code) explaining the new issue ? Having the code will make it easier.

Comment: Updated it. Hope it makes sense now

Comment: So mocking destructures the auth, but since I have another property called isAuthenticated, it is failing as it is undefined. So I am now trying to also mock that, is the correct way perhaps doing something like this: `return jest.fn(() => (mockIsInitialized, mockIsAuthenticated));`

Comment: Why not add `isAuthenticated` to `mockUseAuth` object (directly if does not have to change on per test case basis, otherwise make it dynamic just like `mockIsInitialized`) ?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: That really makes sense but I don't know why it keeps saying cannot destructure property `isAuthenticated` as it is undefined. I didn't modify your answer and I even tried the defineProperty on `isAuthenticated`, no dice.

Comment: Can't say about that, seems like the original question is answered and the `isAuthenticated` issue warrants a separate stackoverflow question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
jest.mock('./hooks/use-auth', () => ({
isInitialized: true
});
```

This basically means that `use-auth` returns an object which has a `inInitialized` property